# Unity 5 Delay em animação

Tags: c#, unity3d

Acabei de criar animação de correr e pular com o unity, mas estou com um problema na hora de o player voltar para o estado inicial o do IdlePlayer, quando eu paro de correr ou pular ele continua por mais 1 segundo, já tentei diminuir os frames mas nada. Segue o meu código abaixo e um print da configuração da animação:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{


    public float velociadade;


    public Transform player ;       
    public Transform Ground;  
    public Animator animator;
    public bool isGround;
    public float force = 200f;    
    public float jumpTime = 0.5f;
    public float jumpDelay = 0.5f;      
    public bool jumped ;

    void Start ()
    {           
        animator = player.GetComponent<Animator> ();    
    }   

    void Update ()
    {
        Movimentar ();
    }

    void Movimentar ()
    {
        isGround = Physics2D.Linecast(this.transform.position,Ground.position,1<<LayerMask.NameToLayer("Plataforma"));


        animator.SetFloat ("run", Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")));


        if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0) {
            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * velociadade * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 0);
        }


        if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < 0) {
            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * velociadade * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 180);
        }




        bool up = Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space);
        if (up && isGround && !jumped)
        {               
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.up * force);
            jumpTime = jumpDelay;
            animator.SetTrigger("jump");   
            jumped = true;


        }


        jumpTime -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (jumpTime <= 0 && isGround && jumped) {
            animator.SetTrigger("ground");
            jumped = false;
        }   
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá. Pelo que dá pra perceber, a sua regra de transição de `runPlayer` para `idlePlayer` é quando o valor de `run` é menor do que `0.1`. Um possível problema que eu enxergo é que o valor de [`Input.GetAxis()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) é no intervalo [-1..1], e assim vai ser negativo (e, consequentemente, menor do que 0.1!) se o jogador se mover para a esquerda, ativando essa transição erroneamente. Talvez você tenha um erro similar na outra transição (de `idlePlayer` para `runPlayer`) que leva erroneamente para `runPlayer`?

Comment: opa isso mesmo, ele esta dando o erro de idleplayer para o runPlayer... eu tentei alterar os valores la e nao funcionou... pelo que eu entendi o b.o esta na hora de pegar o valor em Input.GetAxis()  correto?

Comment: Não exatamente. Do jeito que está, não vai funcionar quando o personagem se mover para a esquerda, porque o valor de `Input.GetAxis()` vai ser negativo (-1), logo menor do que 0.1 e a animação vai mudar de `runPlayer` para `idlePlayer`. Eu assumi que você também tem o problema inverso, porque pelo jeito você *não entendeu* como o `Input.GetAxis()` funciona. Troque o valor na transição de "menor que 0.1" para "igual a 0" e veja se funciona. A ideia é que quando o seu personagem parar de se mover porque o usuário parou de pressionar as setas no teclado, o valor retornado por `GetAxis` vai ser 0.

Comment: Ele esta andando para os dois lados, o problema esta quando eu paro de pressionar as setas tanto para os lados quanto para cima ele continua por mais um segundo mais ou menos correndo ou pulando...

Comment: Hum... eu acho que você é que não entendeu o que eu te falei. Releia os meus comentários e releia a documentação da função `Input.GetAxis()`. O problema não parece ser o movimento, e sim a máquina de estados das animações. Em outras palavras, me parece que as suas regras de transição estão erradas.

Comment: Depois de ler a documentação algumas vezes rs eu entendi... vlw agora esta funcionando ...

Comment: Por nada. Já que você resolveu, por que você mesmo não cria uma resposta explicando em detalhes o que fez pra corrigir? Eu poderia fazê-lo, mas não sei exatamente o que você mudou, então você pode fazer sem problemas. Ter uma resposta aceita é bom porque "marca" a pergunta como respondida e também ajuda mais facilmente outras pessoas no futuro que tiverem problemas similares.

Comment: Opa perfeito, irei subir aqui ... dai já fica registrado como resolvida.. vlw a dica...

Comment: O que foi mudado para arrumar este problema, estou com a mesma dúvida. Aguardo, obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É a animação de transição, aquela outra timeline que fica no inspector quando você seleciona uma transição no animator. Basta clicar nas linhas brancas com setinhas entre um estado e outro, por exemplo, no seu screenshot é a linha que está azul porque está selecionada, entre 'runPlayer' e 'idlePlayer'. 
Repare que o inspector está exibindo uma timeline contendo extamante essas duas animações, seria para você escolher que parte de cada uma seria exibida durante a transição.

[image: transição entre as animações]

A parte circulada em vermelho é a animação que deve ocorrer entre a transição de uma animação para a outra.

Você pode juntar o início e o fim para não ter animação nenhuma e acabar com esse segundo de animação indevida para o seu caso.

Esse vídeo explica mais sobre a animação de transição [animações](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42vf4pJLRQo)

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/58253)

Comment: bem, acho o essencial é que é na timeline da direita, nos detalhes do da transição na aba animator. Mas ok, vou explicar mais aqui na resposta!

Comment: @rubStackOverflow agora está tão bom que você vai até querer aprender Unity